# How to delete nth term word in string?

Tags: c, user-input, stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char str[100];
    int n=0;
    int len=0;
    int space=0;
    printf("sentence : ");
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(str), stdin);

    for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++){
        len+=1;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<len; j++){
        if(str[j]==' '){
            space+=1;
        }
    }

    printf("nth : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
```

When an user inputs a sentence first FOR loop will determine the length and second FOR loop will determine the number of blank space in the sentence. Since every word in the sentence is combined with a space, thus I thought 1 blank space will represent 1 word. However, if user inputs sentence such as 'hello()()world' -> () means blank, my algorithm will count the total number of word as 3 instead of 2.

Moreover, when user inputs nth input as 2, it need to delete second word which is 'world' from 'hello world' and print out only 'hello'. Hereby, what are the possible methods that can be used without <string.h>?

Answer (score 1):

```
char input[] = "    hello      small    world\n"; // or whatever
```

skip leading whitespace

```
char *p = input;
while (*p == ' ') p++;
```

print 1st word

```
while (*p != ' ') putchar(*p++);
```

skip one or more space, one word, and one or more space

```
while (*p == ' ') p++;
while (*p != ' ') p++;
while (*p == ' ') p++;
```

print **one** space and the rest of the input

```
putchar(' ');
while (*p) putchar(*p++);
```

Comment: Pay attention to the `'\0'` string terminator! It may come before the 3rd word if the user *misbehaves*.